# Custom email verification in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have Laravel 8 and Jetstream installed and I need a little help with setting up custom email verification.

I'm currently working on a Unity game which uses Laravel for authentication. So I'm working on adding some extra security by also sending the user's deviceID from Unity to Laravel and would like to verify via email whenever the user logs in from a new device.

I added a migration to add a users_device table to the database which has the following columns: id, email, device, device_verified_at. I'm assuming a user can have more than one authenticated device so I set it up as a separate table from the users table.

The Unity side is all done but I'm having trouble setting it up on Laravel. Initially I tried to piggy-back off of the existing email verification system but I soon realized when a user tries to login from a new device it should ask for email verification but for the old device it should work as normal. By setting $user->email_verified_at = null; this would also lock out the user that's still on the old device.

Can someone here help me set up email verification for deviceIDs?

Comment: did you look at the `Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` `Trait`? there you can override `hasVerifiedEmail` with your relation check

Comment: Yeah, I did. Initially I just added a device column to the user table. I was going through the steps and I realized the way I set it up makes it so that no user can login, even the user on the old device who has already been verified. I realized the problem is kind of complicated and it's hard to do a custom email verification in Laravel.

Comment: you need to also send a custom `job` by overriding `sendEmailVerificationNotification`. To send a custom email with a custom code for it (maybe missing column). The default mail is `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail`

Comment: Yeah, I did that part too. I had a sendDeviceVerificationNotification class. I kept getting 403 errors. I guess I can try again. Too bad it's not like sendEmail(address, msg, callback);

Comment: so what exactly part is failing? did you send a custom code for their device already? Is the Controller which is validating it not right? It is not clear from your question

Comment: I send the device ID from Unity to Laravel. My controller code is good. I had some code which would send the verification email with a link with the email and device verification. I'm not sure why I was getting a 403 so I was hoping to see how other people do it.

Comment: This is through Laravel's API. Not the usual web route if that makes sense.